# Ajax jsonp request. Error: jQuery was not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, jsonp

I want to take some json from server but I have Error:

```
Error: jQuery111106328444090202681_1494341431062 was not called
at Function.error (file:///C:/Users/adm/Documents/temp/WP/wp/www/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:1809)
at h.jsonp.b.dataTypes.(anonymous function).b.converters.script json (file:///C:/Users/adm/Documents/temp/WP/wp/www/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:27648)
at Pc (file:///C:/Users/adm/Documents/temp/WP/wp/www/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:18120)
at x (file:///C:/Users/adm/Documents/temp/WP/wp/www/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:21525)
at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (file:///C:/Users/adm/Documents/temp/WP/wp/www/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:26934)
```

I use jQuery 1.11.1 for jQuery mobile 
It's my js code:

```
function myRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://dev.agro.ws/result.json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).on("pageinit", "#main", function() {
    $('#btnDownload').click(function(event) {
        myRequest();
    });
});
```

Can someone help with my problem?

Comment: because you can not make JSON be JSONP.... The server you are calling needs to support JSONP.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the server you are querying in your `$.ajax` request is returning the result in JSON format instead of JSONP. Take a look at the difference between JSON and JSONP [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114013014/http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html). Here is a basic example in pseudocode (PHP) to check if the request is in fact JSONP

```
$callback = (isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null);
if (isset($callback))
    echo $callback . '([JSON HERE])';
else
    echo '[JSON HERE]';
```

Comment: I need add some php script on server, that catch unique function name and return JSON. 
Does I understand correctly?

Comment: It does not need to be in PHP. I was just using PHP for my example. You will need some server-side language that can read the argument `callback` from the URL. The `callback` argument contains the jQuery function that needs to be used in the JSONP response to the `$.ajax` request

Comment: Thanks a lot, all this stupid guides just describe how to do client side, but you are my hero.